# Sqlite3 var database name

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, tkinter

I was wondering could you create a sqlite3 data base with a variable etc if the user types `data` in, the `data base`should be named `data`.Can this be done?

```
from tkinter import*
import sqlite3
data = e.get()

e = Entry(root) 
e.pack()

conn = sqlite3.connect("data.db")
c = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE #data#<user input#(
#   name text,
#   last text,
#   age interger)""")

root.mainloop()
```

Is there any way that this can be done or is it impossible?
Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't impossible, I believe you are looking for something like this

```py
from tkinter import *
import sqlite3

def create_db():
    conn = sqlite3.connect(f"{e.get()}.db")

root=Tk()

e = Entry(root) 
e.pack()
button=Button(root,text='Create',command=create_db)
button.pack(padx=100)

root.mainloop()
```

The button calls the `create_db` function which creates a database with the name provided in the `Entry`.

Comment: Ok thanks do you know if you can do the same for a table?

Comment: @Rhino Sure, `get` method can be used to retrieve the current text contained by the entry widget (just like you could with any of the [`tkinter` control variables](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/control-variables.html)), you can use that however you want.